# Objective-C IOS callscreen

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, voip

i'm planning to implement a VOIP app for iOS. Is there a possibility to display the built-in callscreen without actually making a call?

Comment: Why would you possibly want to do this?

Comment: @Alexsander Are you asking why OP would want to develop a VOIP app for iOS or why OP wants to display the dialer view without placing a call? The 'this' in your question is ambiguous.

Comment: To be clear, I want to integrate VOIP calling in an app. Therefore it would be nice to have the native callscreen displayed.

Comment: But why would you want to display the call screen if no VOIP call is in place?

Comment: Of course i want to display the call screen if a VOIP call takes place ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the answer to your question, sadly, is no. The "call screen" is part of the Phone app itself, not a resource available to other apps. You'll have to create your own version of the screen, I think.